# Child control is rendered before parent

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form in Angular 8 with 2 custom controls, say 2 text inputs. One control is a simple `control A`, another one is more complex `control B`. The parent page renders `control A`, then `control B`, everything is fine. For some reason, if I move `control B` to a separate component, it gets rendered before `control A`.

**Parent TS**

```
class ParentComponent {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    controlA: [''],
    controlB: ['']
  })
}
```

**Child TS**

```
class ChildComponent {
  @Input() parentForm: FormGroup = null;
}
```

**Child HTML**

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <div controlB></div>
</div>
```

Now, two ways to render the parent, with both controls inside the parent and with `control B` inside child.

**Parent HTML with correct order** - both controls here

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div controlA></div>
  <div controlB></div>
</div>
```

**Parent HTML with wrong order** - for some reason, this renders `control B` then `control A`

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div controlA></div>
  <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

**Question**

How to enforce rendering controls in the order in which they were defined in HTML?

**Alternate question**

Is it possible to set specific order for form inputs if some of these inputs are in child components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, the fix that would require minimal changes would be to set `order: 1` to all controls inside the form and set particular order, e.g. `order: 5` to those that really need it.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .demo-form * { order: 1 }
  .demo-form child-component { order: 5 } /* Should be last */
</style>

<div [formGroup]="myForm" class="demo-form">
  <div controlA></div>
  <div controlB></div>
  <child-component></child-component>
  <div controlC></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add EventEmitter at controlA.

```
@Output() viewLoaded = new EventEmitter();
```

Emit the event at `ngAfterViewInit` hook.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.viewLoaded.next(true);
}
```

At parent ts add a variable.

```
displayControlB: boolean = false;
```

At parent HTML:

```
<div controlA (viewLoaded)="displayControlB = true"></div>
<div *ngIf="displayControlB" controlB></div>
```

HTML may differ according to your implementation, like:

```
<div>
    <controlA (viewLoaded)="displayControlB = true"></controlA>
</div>
```

Comment: `ngIf` can delay rendering, but it can't change the order of the controls on the form.

Comment: Can you reproduce a minimal example at Stackblitz?
It would be helpful.

Comment: I tried to create a simple example, but it appeared to be not reproducible. Comparing it to what I have in the real project, it looks like I have a `flex-column` class from `Bootstrap` assigned to the form tag and all child components are ordered first in HTML. If I remove `flex-column`, everything works fine, so this issue is related to CSS, not Angular. Although, I can't reproduce it in the sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lkgwxk

Comment: Found the mistake. Appeared that all controls in the parent component had CSS `order` property and child components didn't have it, so all child components were automatically pushed before any parent control. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_order

Comment: Haha. Great job.